# Catch a global MouseClick and then repeat it

Tags: c#

My goal is to catch a click anywhere on the screen and then repeat the click.

I will post just a short version of the code here:

```
private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();

m_GlobalHook.MouseClick += MouseClick;

void MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(e.Location.ToString());
  foreach (var coord in coords)
  {
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, coord.X + e.X, coord.X + e.X, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I am using this https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook to speed up my development.

The problem is whenever I call mouse_event in this loop the whole thing stops working, what can be wrong with this?

Comment: When you call `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,...)`, do you generate a Mouse event that, possibly, you handler catches, to generates a new event that causes a new call to `mouse_event` that your handler forwards...?

Comment: I've tried to detach the original event before calling mouse_event, but the same thing happened

Comment: Define *the whole thing stops working* - put a break point in the function and let us know if it gets invoked? Unless it's a second chance exception crashing everything there will be an error.